# MCARI index standard range and formula

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, sentinel-2, scale, formula

What is MCARI's standard range of high and low value. Like NDVI range is from -1 to +1, so is it from -1 to +1 or different because when I am calculating it my range goes up to in thousands. Also if someone can tell me its formula using Sentinel 2 imagery or ARCGIS-desktop's raster calculator.